# Kubernetes 1.4 dashboard is not consistent

Tags: kubernetes

I am creating kubernetes 1.4 cluster and want to access the dashboard once cluster is created. I am deploying cluster on VMs created using apache cloudstack platform. I am using CoreOS for creating the cluster.

However currently I am facing inconsistency of dashboard service access issue.

Sometimes in the same network with exactly same environment when cluster is created a fresh dashboard comes up easily without any issues.

However if I create cluster again in the same environment again (of course by removing the existing cluster) there is no guarantee that dashboard will come up. What I observed is I just cant guarantee if I create the cluster dashboard may come or may not come on exactly the same environment.

When dashboard is not coming up these are the responses I get in browser:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

OR this response:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "endpoints \"kubernetes-dashboard\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "kind": "endpoints"
  },
  "code": 404
}
```

I am not able to get root cause of this issue.

When dashboard is not coming, I checked services running on master. Usually all the services are running except dashboard service: kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler.

Ideally when I run the command `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`
I should see the dashboard container up and running, but it doesn't get listed.

Here are version details I am using:

> Kubernetes api-server version - 1.4.0
>
> client version - 1.4.0
>
> Dashboard service version -
>   gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.5.0
>
> Dashboard yaml is downloaded [from](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/6a82081f2e3d914cb826d8f900e9b88406217300/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml)
>
> CoreOS Version - 1010.5.0

Any help/hint in this regard greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance.

-picku

Comment: `code": 503` k8s-dashboard pod is not running. you need to check the logs of the pod. `kubectl logs k8s-dashboard`

Comment: Side question, why 1.4 once the latest version is 1.8?

Comment: Thanks Suresh for response. I tried running the command - kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard It returned empty response. Usually I run "kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system" command to check if dashboard is running or not. If it is not running then it returns empty response.  I tried running "journalctl -xe" command to check logs. But it just returns that dashboard service is failed without any details error message.

Comment: Regarding 1.8 version usage, True. Will be switching to latest version of K8s but at least for time being have to live with 1.4 version since testing some additional features for my plugin. Just additional note - am creating cluster using my master and node yaml's and automation. So first need to automate those steps for 1.8 version and use it. Actually just replacing the version to 1.8 in my existing 1.4 version yaml's is not working. so looks like some additional things may be required for 1.8 version which are missing. Any pointers on it?